# How do i can fix button bifurcation in PPT?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I tried to create a simple programmable button
[editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY2rZ.png)
and this is what I see when I view the slide
[slide view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Gs6.png)
Button bifurcates!

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Try:  File | Options | Advanced and under Display, put a check next to Disable Screenshow Hardware Graphics Acceleration

Comment: i tried to do that but nothing changed. Thanks for trying

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried trying to fix it by poking at everything I see and saw the monitor selection [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RLSO.png). I have 3 screens, I chose the main monitor. This was the reason.